# How to resolve error in external HTTP request from Node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, axios, httprequest

I'm trying to add an external HTTP request to a Node.js/Express app. When I add this request, I get an error 'ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 '. I get this regardless of whether it is the Post request or a simple Get request to Google for instance. I am behind a corporate proxy that is configured and works with NPM.

For the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/postRequest',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: settings,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, error: function () {
    console.log(data);
    }
    });
```

On the server side:

```
const axios = require('axios');

app.post('/postRequest', function (req, res) {

    axios.get('https://google.com')
    .then(response => {
    res.send(response);
    console.log('Successful response: ', response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log('Unsuccessful response: ', err);
    });
});
```

Here is the full error message:

```
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] toJSON: [Function] }
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] isAxiosError: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] response: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _currentUrl: 'http:https://google.com/' },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] parser: null },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _redirectable: [Circular],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _ended: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] path: 'https://google.com/',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] method: 'GET',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timeout: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] socketPath: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] agent: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _onPendingData: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _headerNames: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _headers: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _header: 'GET https://google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.19.0\r\nhost: google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] connection: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] socket: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _headerSent: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] finished: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _trailer: '',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _hasBody: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _contentLength: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _removedHeader: {},
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sendDate: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] shouldKeepAlive: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] chunkedEncoding: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] upgrading: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _last: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] writable: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] outputSize: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] outputCallbacks: [],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] outputEncodings: [],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] output: [],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _maxListeners: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _eventsCount: 6,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _events: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] domain: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ClientRequest {
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _currentRequest:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _onNativeResponse: [Function],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _requestBodyBuffers: [],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _requestBodyLength: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _redirects: [],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _redirectCount: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] pathname: 'https://google.com/' },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] nativeProtocols: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] host: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] port: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] hostname: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] auth: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] agent: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] headers: [Object],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] maxBodyLength: 10485760,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] maxRedirects: 21,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] { protocol: 'http:',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _options:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _maxListeners: undefined,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _eventsCount: 2,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] { response: [Function: handleResponse],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _events:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] domain: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] writable: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bufferedRequestCount: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] errorEmitted: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] prefinished: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] pendingcb: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] lastBufferedRequest: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bufferedRequest: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] writelen: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] writecb: null,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] onwrite: [Function],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] bufferProcessing: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] sync: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] corked: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] writing: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] length: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] decodeStrings: true,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] finished: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ended: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ending: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] needDrain: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] highWaterMark: 16384,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] objectMode: false,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] WritableState {
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] _writableState:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Writable {
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] request:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] data: undefined },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] maxContentLength: -1,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] timeout: 0,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] host: 'google.com' },
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] headers:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] method: 'get',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] { url: 'https://google.com',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] config:
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] port: 80,
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] address: '127.0.0.1',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] syscall: 'connect',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1099:14)
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
2019-07-15T14:54:41.298-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Unsuccessful response: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be a CORS issue. Post the entire error message and the url that the page is executing under.  Locally you could also have an issue with a firewall blocking binds to addresses other than localhost.

Comment: Added the full server error log

Comment: There is something messed up with your logs. It looks like you have multiple writes all on top of each other?  If you follow their doc guidance on dealing with errors I suspect it would be more readable https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors

Answer (score -9, accepted):

"Locally you could also have an issue with a firewall blocking binds to addresses other than localhost. "

This ended up being the issue. Not a local firewall issue, but something a little more complicated in our firewall setup that was blocking the request.

Comment: Could you please explain how you solved it instead of just saying that you solved it?